# How to change color scheme in a csv plug-in?

Tags: colorscheme, plugin, filetype-csv, plugin-csv

I learnt from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152682/how-to-work-with-csv-files-in-vim) that there is a [csv plug-in](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830). I tried this plug-in and it indeed arranged the csv file well.

However, the color scheme is horrible on my screen.

Is there anyway that I can change the color scheme for this specific plug-in?

I'm satisfied with the current color scheme before I use this plug-in. It will be good if I don't need to change color scheme in other environments.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim/issues

Comment: It's actually in the documentation: https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim/blob/4fd88346aed02123aa5daa1a363868a576c6fdcf/doc/ft-csv.txt#L1263-L1290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors are controlled with the following highlighting groups:

- `CSVDelimiter`
- `CSVColumnEven`
- `CSVColumnOdd`
- `CSVColumnHeaderEven`
- `CSVColumnHeaderOdd`

Here is what I have in my `_vimrc` based on the Nord theme:

```
hi CSVDelimiter guifg=#616E88 guibg=#2E3440
hi CSVColumnEven guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#434c5e
hi CSVColumnOdd guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#2E3440
hi CSVColumnHeaderEven guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#434c5e
hi CSVColumnHeaderOdd guifg=#D8DEE9 guibg=#2E3440
```